# DatePicker arrows clickable but not visible

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker for a field on my form, but the arrows are not visible. If I go to the location where they supposed to be, I can click them to change the month, but the arrows themselves are not visible. What could cause this kind of problem?

Comment: Look to see what the image location for those arrows is, then go to that location and make sure they are present.

Comment: What kind of date-picker, ASP.NET-Calendar, jQuery Datepicker or what else?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be CSS cursor style set to none, something like this:

```
.calendarBox
{
   cursor: None;
}
```